# Crystal Report Viewer is not working in Google chrome IE11 and Safari

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I have an ASP application and this is my first ever crystal report I am doing. The report seems to be all good when I am looking at the reprot in the design and all the data is fine and perfect. However when I try to show it in my Crystal Report Viewer, the report is displyed blank, without data.

Crystal Report Viewer is not working in Google chrome IE11 and Safari but fine in IE8 and IE9

```
Report Viewer print issue in Chrome / Mozilla / Safari: A solution where you can print report contents inside Report Viewer in any browser.
```

In the case of Chrome or Mozilla or in Safari, i can not get print option for Report Viewer to print the report content inside the viewer.How can i solve this.

In my search i found `"Crystal Report Viewer fails for browser versions >=10"`.Is it true?

Is there any solution to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Just include SizeToReportContent="true" as shown below

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" SizeToReportContent="True"...
```